# How to locate an error message at Github?

Tags: python, github

For a python script I am working with, I received this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "label2.py", line 52, in <module>
    main(args.image_file)
  File "label2.py", line 40, in main
    response = service_request.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 755, in execute
    method=str(self.method), body=self.body, headers=self.headers)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 93, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 598, in new_request
    self._refresh(request_orig)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 864, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http_request)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 933, in _do_refresh_request
    raise HttpAccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg, status=resp.status)
oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_scope: Empty or missing scope not allowed.
```

I checked the source at Github: https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/client.py but could not find the error message "Empty or missing scope not allowed."

Is there a methodology to locating error messages at Github corresponding to the error trace? Am I looking at the wrong file? Where should I be looking?

(This is a 'teach me how to fish' rather than 'give me one fish' question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the code that generates that message (line 933 in `oauth2client/client.py`, you can see that the message is coming from the http response from the server.  That's part of the `_do_refresh_request` method, which starts with:

```
      resp, content = http_request(
          self.token_uri, method='POST', body=body, headers=headers)
```

And later sets:

```
          error_msg = 'Invalid response %s.' % resp['status']
```

Which is used in the exception:

```
          raise HttpAccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg, status=resp.status)
```

In other words, the reason you can't find that error message in the source is because it doesn't exist in the source; it is an error generated by the oauth server, delivered to your client as part of an http response.